# How can I calculate deviation from a mean within group for a date excluding the present individual in Excel PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, m

I have the following table and want to calculate the percent deviation from average of a value on a given date  within the remains of the corresponding group using PowerQuery and add as a new column.

| IndividualID | Group | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | date1 | 0.5 |
| A2 | 1 | date1 | 0.6 |
| A3 | 1 | date1 | 0.5 |
| A4 | 2 | date1 | 0.4 |
| A5 | 2 | date1 | 0.3 |
| A6 | 2 | date1 | 0.6 |
| A7 | 2 | date1 | 0.5 |

I have tried filtering by nested `Table.SelectRows()` and `Table.SelectColumns()` within `Filter.Average()`, but always ended up in typecasting errors  like table cannot be casted to list or `null`.

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction from where I am now.

```
fx*=Table.AddColumn(#"Prior Step Name", "deviation of value from group average", 
each [Value]/List.Average(->I think here is where I failed<-))
```

Row 1 as an example should include the following

```
    Filter 1: IndividualID != A1
    Filter 2: Group == 1
    Filter 3: Date == date1
    -->Calculate Average of [Value] for rows matching all Filters above (-> Individuals A2 and A3)
    -->Calculate percent difference of Value for A1 from the calculated average (of A2 and A3)
```

Hope this is precise enough for some input. And thanks in advance!

What I would expect:

| IndividualID | Group | Date | Value | Deviation from group % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | date1 | 0.5 | -9 |

The -9 results from
(Value A1/average(Value A2 + A3) -1) * 100

I would like to calculate this for each indiviual on any given date within the range of the corresponding group.
This is to check how much my Value for an individual differs from the rest of the corresponding experimental group on the given date.

Comment: Before you get an answer, are you sure this is what you want? Deviation from the mean usually includes the value itself as part of the mean calculation.

Comment: I got this description to calculate the formula from a person supervising a trial.
Values will be used as hint to check more detailed for "healthy" and "non-healthy" status based on percentage deviation from mean. We indeed argued whether including a non-healthy A1 would bias the mean of group 1 to make detection weaker.

(The deviation will be calculated with and without A1 and also dependent and independent of groups though as I want to understand PowerQuery better and not only get the problem solved. I just did not find a proper working example with nested referencing and so on yet.)

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"IndividualID", type text}, {"Group", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type text}, {"Value", type number}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group", "Date"}, {{"All", each _, type table [IndividualID=nullable text, Group=nullable number, Date=nullable text, Value=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", (x)=> Table.AddColumn(x[All], "Deviation from group %",(y)=> 
        let a = y[Value],
        b = (List.Sum( x[All][Value]) - y[Value])/ (List.Count(x[All][Value])-1),
        c = (1- (a/b) )* 100
        in c
        )),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Group", "Date", "All"}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"IndividualID", "Group", "Date", "Value", "Deviation from group %"}, {"Custom.IndividualID", "Custom.Group", "Custom.Date", "Custom.Value", "Custom.Deviation from group %"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

Comment: ah. minus iteself

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Group", "Date"}, {{"sum", each List.Sum([Value]), type nullable number}, {"count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}, {"data", each _, type table }}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"IndividualID", "Value"}, {"IndividualID", "Value"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded data", "Variance", try each ([Value]/(([sum]-[Value])/([count]-1))-1)*100 otherwise null),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"sum","count"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: A good solution